# How to force Wordpress admin/login pages with SSL?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, url-rewriting

I have WordPress in a sub-domain like blog.my-site.com and can't use SSL with sub-domains (https:// blog.my-site.com)

Is there a way to force WordPress admin/login pages ONLY to SSL URL https:// www.my-site.com/blog_dir/wp-admin/ (the folder name is not the same as sub-domain)

Comment: issues is I cant get to the admin with sub-domain in SSL so i have to use domain/folder_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the information everyone

Here is a plugin for shared SSL for sub-domain WordPress:
WordPress HTTPS (SSL)
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: This plugin allows you have a blog in sub-domain (blog.my-site.com) and force admin to use SSL from url www.my-site.com/www_blog/

Comment: This plugin is compatible up to 3.5.2 version. :-( Current wordpress version is 4.0.1

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for it!

Answer (score 13):

To [force administration and logins over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL), the proper way is to set the `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` constant in `wp-config.php`.

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if WordPress is hosted behind a reverse proxy that provides SSL.

Paste the following in your theme's functions.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: This worked for me, `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` is required for `wp_register_script` to dynamically change

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: but it redirects to https:// blog.my-site.com than that throws an error about invalid SSL

Comment: then you need to set up an ssl certificate. you can't do it with PHP if you don't already have one. here's a good article: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/security/article.php/3774876/Setting-Up-a-Secure-SSL-Connection.htm

Comment: I have one for the main domain www.my-site.com so only way to use SSL is with www.my-site.com/blog_dir/wp-admin/ but I get redirected to https:// blog.my-site.com/wp-admin/

Comment: you'll need to set up a second certificate for your subdomain. have a look at the article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Added in a plugin or somewhere else where it's included in the pages, this will redirect to the login screen if the protocol is https, and if the user is not already logged in, and if the page is'nt already the login page :

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'query_parser' );

function query_parser() {
  if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
      wp_redirect( home_url() . '/wp-login.php', 302 );
      exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem

the issue was in my front end login function

```
wp_signon( $login_data, false);
```

$secure_cookie by default is none.

I set that to true and it worked great.

```
wp_signon( $login_data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
        exit();
    } else {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add also explanation how this solves the issue?